# how to pass form values and return values of a custom hook when using the useFormik Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

Hi all im new to reactjs. below is the custom reacthook callled useSubmit that i need to pass and fetch data from. on inspection it acepts a url,data argument and returns the isLoading,response and submit method. I believe i need to make an api call to this useSubmit hook. onsubmit:(values) => {/*insert code here*/},

```
import {useState} from "react";

const wait = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

/**
 * This is a custom hook that can be used to submit a form and simulate an API call
 * It uses Math.random() to simulate a random success or failure, with 50% chance of each
 */
const useSubmit = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);

  const submit = async (url, data) => {
    const random = Math.random();
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await wait(2000);
      if (random < 0.5) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }
      setResponse({
        type: 'success',
        message: `Thanks for your submission ${data.firstName}, we will get back to you shortly!`,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      setResponse({
        type: 'error',
        message: 'Something went wrong, please try again later!',
      })
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { isLoading, response, submit };
}

export default useSubmit;
```

I have tried using the hook useSubmit hook directly within the onsubmit(values) => {useSubmit()},
but that violates the rules of hooks as im calling a hook within a hook.I guess i still havent got down some of the react patterns and rules down a pat yet. Hopefully someone can aid me with this.

edit: i have included the code for where this hook will be used.i guess im not sure how i would pass the values and arguments to the for the useSubmit hook to be triggered on submit.

````
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  FormErrorMessage,
  FormLabel,
  Heading,
  Input,
  Select,
  Textarea,
  VStack,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import FullScreenSection from "./FullScreenSection";
import useSubmit from "../hooks/useSubmit";
import {useAlertContext} from "../context/alertContext";


const LandingSection = () => {
  const {isLoading, response, submit} = useSubmit();
  const { onOpen } = useAlertContext();

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName:"",
      email:"",
      type:"",
      comment:""     
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => { /*assuming i would have to pass some onsubmit function here to run the useSubmit hook*/},
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      firstName: Yup.string().required('Required'),
      email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email address').required('Required'),
      type: Yup.string().required('Please pick an option'),
      comment: Yup.string().required('write a comment')
       }),
  });

  return (
    <FullScreenSection
      isDarkBackground
      backgroundColor="#512DA8"
      py={16}
      spacing={8}
    >
      <VStack w="1024px" p={32} alignItems="flex-start">
        <Heading as="h1" id="contactme-section">
          Contact me
        </Heading>
        <Box p={6} rounded="md" w="100%">
          <form onSubmit = {formik.handleSubmit}>```
````

Comment: You should be calling your hooks at the beginning of your component. In your case, you would be calling your custom hook to obtain the returned object that has the `submit` method: `const {submit} = useSubmit();`, which you can then call later on in your onSubmit handler `submit(/* pass the appropriate arguments */)`

Comment: Hey Nick the useSubmit hook has been called at the top of the component, but how would i pass it to the onSubmit function in the formik hook?

the formik.handleSubmit has already been included in the <form/> component.

Comment: When you call `useSubmit()` you'll get back an object which you can extract the `submit` function from (as you've done), you can call this `submit` (not the `useSubmit()`) function you get back inside of formik's `onSubmit` function.

Comment: So `onSubmit: (values) => { submit(url, values)}` assuming those (url, values) are the arguments you want to pass to your submit function (which is defined inside of the `useSubmit()` function)

Comment: onSubmit: (values) => {
    console.log(submit('',values));
    }

i get a promise but there isnt any values for isloading, or response as shown in the custom hook. if i were to just console.log(values)) i do indeed see the values that were submitted from the form.

Comment: You're logging the result of `submit()`, which is an `async` function. The `isLoading` and `response` values are updated within the `submit()` function, and so they'll be reflected in the variables that you destruct here: `const {isLoading, response, submit} = useSubmit();` upon the next render of your component

Comment: Thanks Nick, really appreciate the patience. Just wondering now that i have set up the submit(url,values) in the onsubmit function. is there a way for me to console.log or view the response?

Comment: To view the response you can use it in your JSX,eg: `<p>{response.message}</p>`, or you can log the `response` variable in your component `console.log(response);` (eg: above the `return` statement in your component)